# How to search data from list with checkbox in flutter

Tags: listview, flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-sliver

I want search from the list and also render data into that list with a checkbox. it means in this photo I've data already but when I click on the app bar search box and start searching data it will give me the result based on search data.

Here Is the full source code of project. https://github.com/rutvikgumasana/testing

[image: This is the out of the code]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have implemented a local search for your data in the list. Check below code

initliaise a global list object

```
List<ServicesByCountry> finalList = new List();
```

pass your searchQuery in constructor

```
final BspServiceBloc _bspServiceBloc;
final String searchQuery;
final List<int> servicesIds;
final Map<String, bool> selection;

  const BspServiceScreen({
    Key key,
    @required BspServiceBloc bspServiceBloc,
    @required this.servicesIds,
    @required this.selection,
    this.searchQuery,
  })  : _bspServiceBloc = bspServiceBloc,
        super(key: key);
```

then use below code to search

```
WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
  if (widget.searchQuery != '') {
    finalList.clear();
    lovCountryServices.forEach((ServicesByCountry data) {
      if (data.name
          .toLowerCase()
          .contains(widget.searchQuery.toLowerCase())) {
        setState(() {
          finalList.add(data);
        });
      } else {
        data.services.forEach((Service services) {
          if (services.name
              .toLowerCase()
              .contains(widget.searchQuery.toLowerCase())) {
            setState(() {
              finalList.add(data);
            });
          }
        });
      }
    });
  } else {
    setState(() {
      finalList.clear();
      finalList.addAll(lovCountryServices);
    });
  }
});
```

then pass the final list to your listView widget

Comment: You are Just awesome Man!! :) Exactly what i want :) Thank you so much :)